# TFS API C#: Change work item through C#

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I need to change field `AssignedTo` and `ReadyForQA` in a WorkItem, it does not exist in instance of class `WorkItem` though. 
I need to take value from field `CreatedBy` and set it to field `AssignedTo`, in addition I need to set field `ReadyForQA` to "Yes". It exists in TFS GUI:
[image]
However is doesn't exists in object that returns from query:
[image]
As far as I am concerned, TFS GUI and fields are dynamic and can be created and modified through TFS SQL Database, but maybe exists some way to modify these fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `.Fields["System.FieldName"].Value` property on the Work Item object. Since the values are configurable for each workitem, there are no direct property accessors.

You can use the [`CoreField` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.corefield(v=vs.120).aspx) to find system default fields, your custom field you'll need to access by passing the name. Prefer passing the Enum, then the Reference Name. Don't pass in the Display name. While passing in the Display Name will work, it's a brittle solution.

Comment: Yeah, I've just find out similar solution by myself.
Thanks.
This solution though could throw exception in the case the field doesn't exists.

Comment: But yours is better ))
Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I missed it.